Computer Architecture Math , not taking instruction miss ratio while calculating Secondary but data miss ratio for both primary and secondary?
Suppose you have a processor that uses a 4-stage pipeline and a secondary cache memory. In this processor, the critical parameter value is 4 ns. The cache miss penalty for the primary and secondary cache are 15 clock cycles and 20 clock cycles respectively. The miss ratio for instructions, data, and the secondary cache are 10%, 20%, and 30% respectively. Suppose that 22% of instructions access memory for various operations. Compare the performance of this processor with the performance of a processor consisting of the same configuration but which does not implement pipelining and state which performs better based on throughput.  (((here data  cache is considered for both primary and secondary))) not instruction cache
Should I not include instruction cache while doing math for calculating miss penalty of secondary?

L1I-cache misses can also miss in L2 cache, so you need to consider L2 hit rate when working out both stalls due to data load/store cache misses and stalls due to instruction-fetch cache misses.
They haven't told you what happens when L1i and L1d caches both miss in the same cycle, whether one gets priority to access L2 or whether L2 is dual-ported or something.  Although I guess dual-ported L2 and DRAM is implied by the miss penalties being a flat 15 and 20 cycles...
Also, only 20 cycle miss penalty for L2?  Is that in addition to the L1 miss penalty?  Otherwise that's just 5 extra cycles to go to main memory.  Not that it matters whether these latencies are realistic for real-world CPUs with clock speeds in the 250 MHz range, although you do need to know which they mean to get the answer they're expecting.
